# unzip a dictionary of coordinates and values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I wish to populate the values `x`,`y` and `z`, where `x` are the x coordinates, `y` the y coordinates and `z` the associated values for each coordinate, as defined by `p`. Here is how I am doing it:

```
p = {(1,2): 10, (0,2):12, (2,0):11}
k,z = np.array(list(zip(*p.items())))
x,y = np.array(list(zip(*k)))
```

Is there another more readable way? Perhaps there is something in numpy or scipy for doing this?

Why does `z` result in `array([10, 11, 12], dtype=object)`, while `x` an `y` do not include `dtype=object`?

Comment: `np.array` takes lists (and nested lists) as input, but doesn't do anything special with dictionaries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about as a one-liner?

```
x, y, z = np.array([(x, y, z) for (x, y), z in p.items()]).T
```

This makes it clearer where the values are coming from, without the unnecessary  and unused `k`. Additionally, you should not have the `dtype` issue with this.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why dtype=object?

Consider the second line, now with a single variable assignment:

```
w = np.array(list(zip(*p.items())))
print(w)
```

Here, `w` becomes an array consisting of a row of tuples and a row of ints. Whenever such mixed types are involved, the general `object` datatype (`dtype`) is used. In your code, you effectively have `k, z = w`, and so even though the ints get stored in `z`, they keep their `dtype` (`object`).

#### A cleaner way

In one line we can do

```
x, y, z = np.array([(x, y, z) for (x, y), z in p.items()]).T
```

Here, a list is generated storing tuples of the form `(x, y, z)`. This is then converted to a 2D NumPy array. Finally, this array (or matrix) is transposed (the `.T`) and then assigned to `x`, `y` and `z`. The transposition is needed as otherwise, the rows of the matrix will be assigned to `x`, `y` and `z` (try leaving out the `.T` and see the effect for yourself).

Answer (score 1):

If you used Pandas, the solution would be very readable:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series(p)
#0  2    12
#1  2    10
#2  0    11
```

If eventually you want numpy arrays:

```
x = data.reset_index()['level_0'].values
y = data.reset_index()['level_1'].values
z = data.values
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I like numpy I would go with the following:

```
keys = np.array(list(p.keys()))
vals = np.matrix(list(p.values()))
comb = np.concatenate((keys, vals.T), axis=1)
x, y, z = comb.T
```

How readable that is depends on how used to are to numpy.

There are two tricks in there. The first is that the sorting of dictionary items does not change if the dictionary did not change so we can call keys and values separately. The second is to use np.matrix for the values so that transpose works because transposing a 1D array in numpy is a nop.